# Problema al crear paquete de instalación Visual Studio 2022 C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Intentaré ser lo más especifico posible. He terminado una aplicación windowforms en C# y quería crear un instalador. Agrego nuevo proyecto con "Setup project" "Create a Windows Installer project to which files can be added".

Sigo todos los pasos que encontré en varios tutoriales, añadir iconos, accesos directos, etc.
Compilo y el archivo de instalación se ha creado. Instalo mi app y cuando voy a ejecutar la aplicación no funciona. No hay errores, simplemente no hace nada.

No hay errores en la compilación del setup. El icono en el escritorio aparece despues de la instalación. Todo parece bien, y no se que puede estar pasando.

Llevo varios días intentándolo y no tengo experiencia con Visual Studio, si alguien a pasado por esto se agradece la ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Al parecer es problema de la aplicación, no del instalador. Generalmente este tipo de errores sucede por las rutas relativas, por ejemplo veo que usas SQLite, puede ser que no encuentre la base de datos. También puede pasar con referencias a dll, imagenes u otros recursos

Comment: ¿no debería mostrar error si no encuentra la BD? De hecho lo implemente con código, sino la encuentra marca error y lo añade a un archivo log, y eso no pasa. Lo que si me he dado cuenta es que en mi carpeta bin/debug hay un ejecutable y el archivo bd y funciona, pero en la instalación no está el archivo db. Aunque copio y pego tampoco funciona.  Las rutas en la app son relativas .\ no deberían dar problemas

Comment: *¿no debería mostrar error si no encuentra la BD?* No sé, tú dinos. Cómo manejas los errores en la aplicación? De igual forma, no hay suficiente información para saber cuál es el problema. Qué tipo de máquina corre el sistema, cuál versión del SO, cuál es la versión del framework? Es x86 o x64? Está instalado SQL Lite en el ordenador? Tal vez hay que ser más específico

Comment: Toda la app tiene su try/catch, y genera un archivo txt con la excepción. El sistema es windows 10 21h2. Procesador AMD FX 8150 con 20GB 64 bits. La app utiliza el framework 4.6 está instalado en el PC. SQLite está instalado en el pc. Se prueba compilar tanto para x86 como x64 sin éxito.  Como digo, debería ser problema del instalador, pues la versión de bin/debug funciona perfectamente al ejecutar el .exe.

Comment: He podido avanzar un poco. Me he dado cuenta que la app no se iniciaba, pero si cuando la ejecuto con permisos de administrador. Al ejecutarse solicita una clave de acceso que está en la bd, y aunque la ponga da error. según el Log no encuentra la base de datos. Pero si veo que en el directorio Release si está. Parece como si al crear el instalador la bd se perdiese.  La app la instala en el directorio: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\..\YourSecretDay\bin\Debug\     Aquí veo que no está el archivo de la bd pero  si están los Dll de Sqlite y el .exe de la app